# Playing video streams - smoothstream / playready / hasplayer.js

Tags: javascript, video

I am trying to play a source encoded in microsoft smoothstream and encrypted with playready using the hasplayer.js.

I can get a microsoft test stream to play but when I try to use my encrypted stream the player just sits there showing the dots for loading and does not return an error or show any video or audio.

My javascript function.

```
(function () {
    console.log("Setting video url");

    var onError = function (e) {
        console.error("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    };
    // Microsoft sample stream
    //var url = "http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/SSWSS720H264/SuperSpeedway_720.ism/Manifest";

    // my  test stream smoothstream & playready
    var url = "http://stream.abcdef.net/stream/file/hd/smooth/file_encrypted.ism/manifest";

    var context = new MediaPlayer.di.Context();
    var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
    player.startup();
    player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"));
    player.addEventListener("error", onError);
    player.attachSource(url);
})();
```

Comment: Should have added that i know the stream is good as it plays in the silverlight demo at http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/slee/.

Answer (score 1):

After using the hasplayer debug and contacting the hasplayer team. it was found that our stream had a box type that was unknown to the hasplayer and this caused an error.

The hasplayer team are looking at a fix and we are looking at our stream generation.